# how to call shell commands from groovy correctly

Tags: file, shell, groovy, command

i want to execute shell commands from my groovy  script.
I tested the following:

```
"mkdir testdir".execute()
```

and this just  works fine.
Now i wanted to make a file, write something to the file and then open a text editor to view the  file.

```
def execute(cmd) {
   def proc =  cmd.execute()
   proc.waitFor()
}

execute("touch file")
execute("echo hello > file")
execute("gedit file")
```

Now gedit  opens correctly but ther is no "hello" string in the file.
How is this working?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do redirection in the line:

```
execute("echo hello > file")
```

So nothing gets written to the file.  The easiest way to handle this is probably to wrap all your commands into a single shell script, then execute this script.

Otherwise, you can read the standard output from the `echo` command (without the `> file`), and then write this to `file` yourself in Groovy.

Or you can do:

```
execute( [ 'bash', '-c', 'echo hello > file' ] )
```

Which should work as your `execute` method will just perform [the `List.execute()` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#execute%28%29)

Comment: I don't know anything about `groovy`; that said, is there a way to tell the `execute` method to pass the command line to a shell for processing before execution, like the `shell=True` option for the Python `subprocess` module?

Comment: @chepner Actually, you're right...there is a way... added to the answer