# Run a compound shell command from Java/Groovy

Tags: java, bash, shell, groovy

I got stuck trying to run a compound shell command from a Groovy script. It was one of those commands where you separate with "&&" so that the 2nd command never runs if the 1st one fails. For whatever reason I couldn't get it to work. I was using:

```
println "custom-cmd -a https://someurl/path && other-cmd -f parameter".execute([], new File('/some/dir')).text
```

The shell kept misinterpreting the command throwing errors like "custom-cmd -f invalid option" It was like it was ignoring the "&&" in between. I tried using a semi-colon as well but was not lucky. I tried using straight Java APIs Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and splitting the command into an array. I tried wrapping the command in single quotes and giving it to '/bin/sh -c' but nothing works.

How do you run a compound shell command from Java? I know I've done this in the past but I cannot figure it out today.

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape the &&.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call shell commands from groovy correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512919/how-to-call-shell-commands-from-groovy-correctly).  you can not use "shellism" like && < | as commands.  use `-c` and pass it as _one_ param (easiest done by string array, if the quoting gets tricky)

Answer (score 2):

With groovy, the list form of execute should work:

```
def out = ['bash', '-c', "custom-cmd -a https://someurl/path && other-cmd -f parameter"].execute([], new File('/some/dir')).text
```

Of course you may want to use the `consumeProcessOutput` method on process, as if the output is too large, calling text may block

Comment: This works! Thank you! It was not working when I passed /bin/sh as the executable but bash seems to work. Also I did not know that List also supports the execute method! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"start somefile.bat && start other.bat && cd C:\\test && test.exe\"");`

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` can be used without splitting the commands into an array.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867097/1410671

EDIT:

Have you tried using a `ProcessBuilder`?  This seems to work on my OSX box:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo '123' && ls" );

    Process p=null;
    try {
        p = builder.start();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    Scanner s = new Scanner( p.getInputStream() );
    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println( s.next() );
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: As explained above, I already tried something like this. (I'm on OSX) I used /bin/sh -c 'cmd && othercmd'

Comment: Also, I've tried both  splitting and not splitting the cmd. Usually splitting on white space works better but not in this case.